# How to simulate a "click" event in Haskell

Tags: javascript, haskell, jsdom, ghcjs

I want to internally click a button in Haskell, and I'm using (maybe I'm wrong)
the function dispatchEvent_ https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-dom-0.9.4.1/docs/JSDOM-Generated-EventTarget.html.
My code is the following:

```
event  <- (toJSVal "click" )
dispatchEvent_ (button_run :: HTMLButtonElement) (MouseEvent event  )
```

However I encounter the following runtime error:

> Argument 1 ('event') to EventTarget.dispatchEvent must be an instance of Event.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know much about jsaddle-dom, but isn't this what you want? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-dom-0.9.4.1/docs/JSDOM-Generated-HTMLElement.html#v:click

Comment: The types don't match; I need to pass to dispatchEvent something of type "isEvent"; click has a different type.

Comment: Do you need `dispatchEvent`? `click` itself simulates it without `dispatchEvent`, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, sure thanks a lot; I was looking to the wrong "click": https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-dom-0.9.0.0/docs/JSDOM-Generated-GlobalEventHandlers.html, while the "click" I needed was https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-dom-0.9.4.1/docs/JSDOM-Generated-HTMLElement.html#v:click. Really really thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Made it an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JSDOM.Generated.HTMLElement.click`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-dom-0.9.4.1/docs/JSDOM-Generated-HTMLElement.html#v:click) to fire a click event on your `HTMLButtonElement`.